# Is this a matrix operator norm?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Is the max element-wise norm a matrix operator norm?

I know a matrix operator norm is defined by 
$$
|A|_p=\sup_{v≠0} \frac{|Av|_p}{|v|_p}
$$

But how can I tell if the max norm is an operator norm?

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format your question :)

Comment: Are you asking about the norm given by
$$
\sup_{v \neq 0} \frac{|Av|_\infty}{|v|_\infty}
$$
or the function
$$
n(A) = \max_{i,j} |a_{ij}|
$$
which is not a matrix norm?

Comment: @alw: since you now know the answer, I suggest you post an answer yourself, showing that the max norm is an operator norm when the 1-norm is considered in the domain, and the infinity-norm in the codomain. You can also prove that it is not an operator norm with the definition you posted in the question, where you require the same norm in the domain and the codomain.

Comment: How should I go about showing the case where the domain is 1-norm and the codomain is infinity norm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a norm.

**Operator norms.** Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$, $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be two normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ a linear operator. $T$ is bounded, if there exists a $c>0$, such that
$$
\|Tx\|_Y\le c\|x\|_X, \quad\text{for all $x\in X$}.\qquad (\star)
$$
The infimum of all $c$ satisfying the above, also satisfies the above and it is the operator norm $\|T\|$. In fact
$$
\|T\|=\inf\{c:c \,\,\,\text{satifies $(\star)$}\}=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Tx\|_Y}{\|x\|_X}
=\sup_{\|x\|_X=1}\|Tx\|_Y.
$$
So an *operator norm* is one defined as $\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Tx\|_Y}{\|x\|_X}$.